# How to get the MAX Id value from a table in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to update the table data with some row that should have defined a `MAX Id + 1` value for the `Movement Id` field which is the **PK** in my table.

The **Movement Id** field is the `INT` **PK**, the **Added At** field is a `date` and the **IncOutc** is the `INT` field that can store either 1 or 2(Income or Outcome).

**query.sql**

```
DECLARE @max_id INT;
SET @max_id = SELECT MAX([Movement Id]) FROM Movement

INSERT INTO Movement([Movement Id], [Added At], IncOutc) 
VALUES (max_id, GETDATE(), 1)
```

I tried the query above but got an error: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.` (on line 1).

I already tried inserting the values like this:

```
VALUES (SELECT MAX([Movement Id]) FROM Movement, max_id, GETDATE(), 1)
```

But got an error saying: `Incorrect syntax near '1'.` (on line 4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't.  You use an `IDENTITY` column or `SEQUENCE` when you create the table.  So:

```
CREATE TABLE Movements (
    Movement_Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Added_At DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    IncOutc Int
);
```

Then you insert to it as:

```
INSERT INTO Movements (IncOutc)
     VALUES (1);
```

`Movement_Id` and `Added_At` are given appropriate default values on the insert.

Attempting to do this outside the database is *very* problematic.  In particular, two inserts at the same time might generate the same id in the table -- presumably not what you want.  Preventing that requires locking the table, which is very expensive.  Especially considering that SQL Server has built-in functionality to do this.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your actual question, you use:

```
SET @max_id = (SELECT MAX([Movement Id]) FROM Movement);
```

Notice the statement terminator. That is a good habit to develop. You might wonder what happens when your table has no rows. I suggest you try it and see for yourself.